# Overwriting LessPHP variable with PHP

Tags: php, less

I use [LessPHP](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) (v0.3.4-2), read the documentation and search around this -basic- question but still not found the correct and straight answer.

Here is my .less file:

```
@bgcolor :#ccc; 
.color(@color:#222) { color:@color; }

body {
  margin:10px auto;
 .color(@color);
 background:@bgcolor;
}
```

My php code:

```
<?php
include 'lessc.inc.php';

$style_setting = array (
  'color'       => '#f00',
  'bgcolor'    => '#fee'
);

$cssFile    = "stylesheet.css";
$lessFile    = new lessc("less/stylesheet.less");
file_put_contents($cssFile, $lessFile->parse(null, $style_setting));
?>
```

Stylesheet result:

```
body {
  margin:10px auto;
  color:#ff0000;
  background:#cccccc;
}
```

As you see on example above, the LesPHP arguments (*.color(@color:#222)*) is overwrited but the *@bgcolor* variable is not.

Just wondering is it correctly how LessPHP work or do I miss something here? Why does the LessPHP variable is not overwrited?

Any answer or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have the same implementation of `@bgcolor` as `.color`?

If the following works for `@color`:

```
.color(@color:#222) { color:@color; }
```

then the following should work for `@bgcolor`:

```
.bgcolor(@bgcolor:#ccc) { background:@bgcolor; }
```

**Update, an explanation of what is happening:**

Let's assume this was all written in PHP, this is what a `.color` *function* would look like:

```
function color($color = null) {
    if(!$color) {
        return 'color: #222;';
    }
    return 'color: $color;';
}
echo color(); //outputs "color: #222222;"
echo color('#f00'); //outputs "color: #ff0000;"
echo color(); //outputs "color: #222222;"
```

It takes the colour value passed OR outputs a default value. Now, this is what is happening with the `@bgcolor` *variable*:

```
$bgcolor = '#fee';
$bgcolor = '#ccc';
echo 'color: '.$bgcolor.';'; //outputs "background: #cccccc;"
```

They key difference is that `.color` is a function that can take values and `@bgcolor` is a variable.

You've effectively defined what you want, instantly overwritten it and then called the variable. The only way to make it dynamic is to turn it into a 'function' like you have with `color`.

Comment: Yes, I know that will work. I'm just wondering why does variable isn't overwrited, just incase I miss something there. But if this is actually how the LessPhp work, I will use the arguments.

Comment: Updated with an explanation of what the problem is, hopefully it makes sense!

Comment: Thank you, make sense and understand it now :)